# TextField shrinking/scrolling when keyboard appears using keyboard_actions package flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I am using keyboard_actions 3.1.2 https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions and my text field is hiding when keyboard appears on screen . I have attached three images of my problem on iOS where you can see

1. a pop up which is asking to input number
2. when i am typing the number my text box is not visible. - keyboard appearing on screen
3. Once i click on Done , my text is appearing. - keyboard closed

pop up i have used is stateless widget.
below is my code .

```
FocusNode _nodeText1 = FocusNode();



 KeyboardActionsConfig _buildConfig(BuildContext context) {
return KeyboardActionsConfig(
  keyboardActionsPlatform: KeyboardActionsPlatform.ALL,
  keyboardBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
  nextFocus: true,
  actions: [
    KeyboardAction(
      focusNode: _nodeText1,
      closeWidget: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Text(
          "CLOSE",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Dialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Consts.padding),
  ),
  elevation: 0.0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  child: Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Consts.padding),
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[

      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
          height: 40,
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

          child: KeyboardActions(
            config: _buildConfig(context),
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              //  controller: oTPInputController,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              focusNode: _nodeText1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Input Number",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:
                      BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark),
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:
                      BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

      ),

    ],
  ),
),
);}
```

> [1. pop up which is asking to input number][1] [2. i am typing the
>   number my text box is not visible][2] [3. Once i click on Done , my
>   text is appearing][3]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHNw4.png
>   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCjoV.png   [3]:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/68NRV.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's odd. It's a current issue in the library itself. See [this github issue](https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter_keyboard_actions/issues/48).

My suggestions:

1. Set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` in `Column` build method.
2. If you have an `ScrollView`-derived class, `AnimatedList` or `ListView` set `shrinkWrap: false`.
3. Set `autoScroll: false` in `KeyboardAction`, and try setting either `areaToAvoid: 0` or `overscroll: 0`.
4. In the screen containing/showing/presenting the dialogue, try setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false` in the Scaffold build method ([Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html)).

Honestly responsiveness to keyboard notifications isn't that great in Flutter. For [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19279#issuecomment-553742546) it's not possible to sync animation of moving some widget upwards/downwards with keyboard opening/closing animation.

Well done on the detailed question and conveying your problem correctly. HTH

Comment: Hello , Thanks for your response. I am returning Dialog from this page and that's why i don't want to use Scaffold. its a small dialogue box just for taking OTP. thanks for highlighting same issue on GitHub , i have asked for update there too. thanks

Comment: @shrutitupkari I updated my answer. In that case please try suggestion #1, #2, and #3 (#4 is the scaffold modification, don't have to do that since you don't want to use Scaffold)

Please try them out and let me know if any of those suggestions worked.

You're welcome.